# error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new dotnet core MVC app using yeoman on OSX. I did `dotnet restore` & `dotnet publish`. Then I pushed it to Github & at azure I added Github repo & that should automatically deployed my website to azure but I see this error

**dotnet info**

```
Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.12
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
```

**logs**

```
Installing Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.0.1.
Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.1.0.
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\project.json...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/index.json 141ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/1.1.0-preview4-final/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools.1.1.0-preview4-final.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/1.1.0-preview4-final/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools.1.1.0-preview4-final.nupkg 22ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.1.1.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.1.1.0.nupkg 25ms
Installing Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils 1.1.0.
Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\repository\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\project.json
Restore completed in 240318ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1ivdstudios\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
    320 package(s) to D:\home\site\repository\project.json
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.545.13942
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\home\site\repository\project.json(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "project.json" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d45033fdf16040" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.60207.2684\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Comment: did  you tried and get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To add a global.json at the root directory of your projects

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
}}
```